# Grails 1.3.9 JSON convert Double.NaN values

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm having a tree of domain classes that i want to convert to JSON via a deep converter:

```
import grails.converters.deep.JSON

deepObject as JSON
```

Somewhere in the tree I'm having Double.NaN values in some fields and the JSON parser throws an exception:

`org.apache.commons.lang.UnhandledException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONException: JSON does not allow non-finite numbers`

How can I handle that case? May be returning a string ('NaN').

I tried repacing the *JSONObject.testValidity(Object o)* method, but this is a pojo and so it does not work.

*Edit*

I also tried to register a marshaller in Bootstrap.groovy:

```
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Double) {
    return it == Double.NaN ? 'NaN' : it.toString()
}
```

But it also wont work.

Comment: Maybe the [gson plugin](https://github.com/robfletcher/grails-gson) could help?  It has a `grails.converters.gson.serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues` property which seems to do what you want?

Comment: @tim_yates Thanks, but it seems that this plugin needs at least Grails 2.2. My project is using 1.3.9.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately most native values rendering is hardcoded in `grails.converters.JSON`, and can't be personalized with `registerObjectMarshaller`. One solution is to specify the JSON converter class and override its `value(Object o)` method as:

```
import grails.converters.JSON

class MyJSONConverter extends JSON {

    @Override
    public void value(Object o) throws ConverterException {
        if (o instanceof Double && o.NaN)
            o = 'Nan'
        super.value(o);
    }
}
```

and call your custom implementation with

```
import org.grails.web.converters.ConverterUtil
import org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest

MyJSONConverter myJSONConverter = ConverterUtil.createConverter( MyJSONConverter.class, deepObject,  GrailsWebRequest.lookup()?.applicationContext);
String deepString = myJSONConverter as String;
```